# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn: limit MaxDropDownItems

Tags: c#, combobox, datagridviewcombobox

I would like to know how to limit the number of items to show in `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.
In simple `ComboBox` we can do it as:

```
comboBox1.IntegralHeight = false; //this is necessary to make it work!!!
comboBox1.MaxDropDownItems = 3;
```

But how to do the same in `DGV`s comboBox`?

When creating `ComboBoxColumn` there is no `IntegralHeight` property.

Answer (score 3):

I have figured it out by my self, by subscribing to `DataGridViewEditControlShowing` event, and with this code inside of it:

```cs
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(
    object sender, 
    DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cb = e.Control as ComboBox;
    if (cb != null)
    {
        cb.IntegralHeight = false;
        cb.MaxDropDownItems = 10;
    }
}
```

Now the dropdown menu works, it shows as many rows as set for the `MaxDropDownItems` property.

For Visual Basic

```vb
Private Sub dgvDesp_EditingControlShowing( _
    sender As Object, _
    e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles dgvDesp.EditingControlShowing
    Dim cb As ComboBox = e.Control
    If cb.Items.Count > 0 Then
        cb.IntegralHeight = False
        cb.MaxDropDownItems = 10
    End If
End Sub
```